# insert values to database after looping through a form

Tags: php, mysql

Briefly, my script includes form ask how many images to enter ,,the entered value will be in a while loop that will display a form with inputs equally to image value entered . okey , I made the submit button outside the loop ,I want now to add them to database ,,I used again a while loop with the query as I did in the form ,,but it only inserts the last item ..What could the problem be ? This is part of the script :

```
if (isset($_POST["chooseimagen"])) {
    $i=0;
    $imgvl = $_POST["imgvl"];
    $cid = $_POST["cid"];
    while($i<$imgvl){

       echo '<form name="finalform" method="post" action="">
        id of content :<input type="text" name="idcontent" value="'.$cid.'"/><br><br>
       Enter id of image :<input type="text" name="imgid" value=""/><br><br>
       Enter name of image : <input type="text" name="imgname" value=""/><br><br>
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
       '; 
       $i++; 
    }

  echo  "<br><br><input type='hidden' name='imgvl' value='".$imgvl."'/><input type='submit' name='addto' value='insert images'/></form";  
}  

    ?>
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST["addto"])){
  $imgvl = $_POST["imgvl"];
     $i=0;
     while ($i < $imgvl){
     $idcontent = $_POST["idcontent"];
     $imgid = $_POST["imgid"];
     $imgname = $_POST["imgname"];
     $queryin = "insert into content_images values ('$imgid','$idcontent','$imgname','ok')";
     mysqli_query($con,$queryin);
         $i++;
     }

 }   


?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) instead.

Comment: I know I am just testing

Comment: You should "just test" using prepared statements.

Comment: Yep, you should test using prepared statements. Because if you don't, then when you come to change your code later to put them in, you have to re-test everything anyway to make sure you didn't make a mistake, so it's just a big waste of time. Alternatively, you might forget to change it, and leave your application vulnerable. If you know how to do it properly, then do it properly from the beginning. People say "this is just test code, I'll throw it away and start again properly", but they never do, because working (but poor quality) code is too valuable because of the time spent on it.

Answer (score 0):

Still new to development, but I think I know..

A few things, you are creating a new form with every loop, but only closing it once. Also you are missing a >, so technically you are not closing the forms at all.

```
while($i<$imgvl){

   echo '<form name="finalform" method="post" action="">
```

...

```
$i++; 
}

echo  "<br><br><input type='hidden' name='imgvl' value='".$imgvl."'/>
<inputtype='submit' name='addto' value='insert images'/></form";
```

But I think the reason you are getting this problem is each form you create has the same names for the inputs. That's why you are only getting the last item, because every item you are inserting is just the last input set.

Because you have no action on the form, every form is essentially combined. This means there is no way to distinguish which input name you are reffering to and therefore it takes the last value that was assigned.

Hope this helps

Comment: no I think I have to make the inputs names as arrays ex: user[] , but I have no knowledge on how to do it . Any way if you can test what you have said in a simple example that would be great .

Comment: Im not going to write it for you. But if you use your loops to your advantage it will work. Make the names like this name="contentid' . $i . ' " This will automatically assign an unqiue id to each input. Then you just need to do the same with the insert functions.